# How to load multiple chrome extensions in Chrome browser using Selenium java?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

I got the below code to open Chrome browser using Selenium with extension enabled. To enable multiple chrome extensions, do I need to repeat the steps or is there any simpler way?

```
String pathToExtension = “C:\\Users\\home\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Extensions\\mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi\\2.3.1_0”;
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments(“–-load-extension=” + pathToExtension);
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 1):

Separate the path with a comma for the next one:

```
--load-extension=path/to/extension,path/to/another/extension
```

Solution from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782557/load-unpacked-chrome-extension-programmatically